# Hibernate QueryException Named parameter not bound error

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa, java-ee-8

I keep getting the error **org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : item** when I start my transaction in JPA using EntityManager createNativeQuery.  I have my code below utilizing the entity manager, along with my embeddedID class (for the composite key) and my persistence entity bean.  Is there a problem in my query syntax?  I am not sure as I've tried multiple ways of formatting the sql (coming from a properties file where there resides multiple sqls used throughout the project, and attempting to persist data to an oracle db).  I am not sure why I keep falling on this error.  I want to persist this data to my oracle database but this error keeps preventing that.

Query from query.properties file:

```
insertPromoData =INSERT INTO TEST.U_USER_PROMO (ITEM, LOC, WK_START, NUMBER_OF_WEEKS, TYPE, FCSTID, QTY, U_TIMESTAMP) VALUES (:item, :location, :wkStart, :numberOfWeeks, :type, :fcstId, :quantity, SYSDATE)
```

Embeddedable Class for establishing composite primary key on the target table:

```
@Embeddable
public class PromoID implements Serializable {
 
    @Column(name = "ITEM")
    private String item;
 
    @Column(name = "LOC")
    private String loc;
    
    @Column(name = "WK_START")
    private Date weekStart;
    
    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private int type;
    
    @Column(name = "FCSTID")
    private String forecastId;
    
    @Column(name = "U_TIMESTAMP")
    private Timestamp insertTS;
    
    public PromoID() {
        
    }
    
    public PromoID (String item, String loc, Date weekStart, int type, String forecastId, Timestamp insertTS) {
        this.item = item;
        this.loc = loc;
        this.weekStart = weekStart;
        this.type = type;
        this.forecastId = forecastId;
        this.insertTS = insertTS;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public Date getWeekStart() {
        return weekStart;
    }

    public void setWeekStart(Date weekStart) {
        this.weekStart = weekStart;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getForecastId() {
        return forecastId;
    }

    public void setForecastId(String forecastId) {
        this.forecastId = forecastId;
    }

    public Timestamp getInsertTS() {
        return insertTS;
    }

    public void setInsertTS(Timestamp insertTS) {
        this.insertTS = insertTS;
    }

    //removed hashcode and equals methods for simplicity
```

Persistence Entity Bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "U_USER_PROMO")
public class InsertPromoData {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PromoID id;

    /*@Column(name="BATCH_ID")
    String batchID;*/
    
    @Column(name="ITEM")
    String item;
    
    @Column(name="LOC")
    String loc;
    
    @Column(name="WK_START")
    String weekStart;
    
    @Column(name="TYPE")
    String type;
    
    @Column(name="FCSTID")
    String forecastId;
    
    @Column(name="U_TIMESTAMP")
    String insertTS;
    
    @Column(name="NUMBER_OF_WEEKS")
    String numberOfWeeks;
    
    @Column(name="QTY")
    String qty;
    
    @Id
    @AttributeOverrides(
            {
                @AttributeOverride(name = "item",column = @Column(name="ITEM")),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "loc", column = @Column(name="LOC")),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "weekStart", column = @Column(name="WK_START")),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name="TYPE")),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "forecastId", column = @Column(name="FCSTID"))
            }
    )

    public PromoID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(PromoID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public String getWeekStart() {
        return weekStart;
    }

    public void setWeekStart(String weekStart) {
        this.weekStart = weekStart;
    }

    public String getNumberOfWeeks() {
        return numberOfWeeks;
    }

    public void setNumberOfWeeks(String numberOfWeeks) {
        this.numberOfWeeks = numberOfWeeks;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getForecastId() {
        return forecastId;
    }

    public void setForecastId(String forecastId) {
        this.forecastId = forecastId;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getInsertTS() {
        return insertTS;
    }

    public void setInsertTS(String insertTS) {
        this.insertTS = insertTS;
    }
}
```

My dao OracleImpl.java using EntityManager for persisting:

```
public void insertPromoData(List<InsertPromoData> insertData) {
          logger.debug("Execution of method insertPromoData in Dao started");
         
          EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
                  
          try {
              em.getTransaction().begin();    
              System.out.println("Beginning transaction for insertPromoData");
              Query query = em.createNativeQuery(env.getProperty("insertPromoData"));
              for (InsertPromoData promoData : insertData) {
                  query.setParameter("item", promoData.getItem());
                  query.setParameter("location", promoData.getLoc());
                  query.setParameter("wkStart", promoData.getWeekStart());
                  query.setParameter("numberOfWeeks", promoData.getNumberOfWeeks());            
                  query.setParameter("type", promoData.getType());
                  query.setParameter("fcstId", promoData.getForecastId());
                  query.setParameter("quantity", Double.valueOf(promoData.getQty()));
              }
              query.executeUpdate();
              System.out.println("Data for promo persisted");
              em.getTransaction().commit();
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
              logger.error("Exception in beginning transaction");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally {
              em.clear();
              em.close();
          }
            
          logger.debug("Execution of method insertPromoData in Dao ended");
    }
```

PromoValidator.java class:

```
List <InsertPromoData> insertPromos = new ArrayList<>();
promo.forEach(record -> {
        
        if (record.getErrorList().size() == 0) {
            rowsSuccessful++;
            record.setItem(record.getItem());
            record.setLoc(record.getLoc());
            record.setNumber_Of_Weeks(record.getNumber_Of_Weeks());
            record.setForecast_ID(record.getForecast_ID());
            record.setType(record.getType());
            record.setUnits(record.getUnits());
            record.setWeek_Start_Date(record.getWeek_Start_Date());
            
            insertPromos = (List<InsertPromoData>) new InsertPromoData();
            for (InsertPromoData insertPromoData : insertPromos) {
                insertPromoData.setItem(record.getItem());
                insertPromoData.setLoc(record.getLoc());
                insertPromoData.setWeekStart(LocalDate.parse(record.getWeek_Start_Date()));
                insertPromoData.setNumberOfWeeks(Integer.parseInt(record.getNumber_Of_Weeks()));
                insertPromoData.setType(Integer.parseInt(record.getType()));            
                insertPromoData.setForecastId(record.getForecast_ID());
                insertPromoData.setQty(Double.parseDouble(record.getUnits()));
            }
            
        } else {
            if (rowsFailure == 0) {
                Util.writeHeaderToFile(templateCd, errorFile);
            }
            rowsFailure++;
            Util.writeErrorToFile(templateCd, errorFile, record, record.getErrorList());
        }
    });
    
    errorFile.close();
    successFile.close();
    
    OracleImpl.insertPromoData(insertPromos);
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason this can happen is when `insertData` List you are passing is empty.

If I use below code ( please note that I have removed few columns to simplify it on my test environment with H2 database) - I get the error you described if empty list is passed and that's because there is indeed nothing to bind for the name parameter as the loop is not executed.

```
try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            System.out.println("Beginning transaction for insertPromoData");
            
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
                    "INSERT INTO U_USER_PROMO (ITEM, LOC, WK_START, NUMBER_OF_WEEKS, TYPE, FCSTID, QTY) VALUES (:item, :location, :wkStart, :numberOfWeeks, :type, :fcstId, :quantity)");
            for (InsertPromoData promoData : insertData) {
                query.setParameter("item", promoData.getId().getItem());
                query.setParameter("location", promoData.getId().getLoc());
                query.setParameter("wkStart", promoData.getId().getWeekStart());
                query.setParameter("numberOfWeeks", promoData.getNumberOfWeeks());
                query.setParameter("type", promoData.getId().getType());
                query.setParameter("fcstId", promoData.getId().getForecastId());
                query.setParameter("quantity", Double.valueOf(promoData.getQty()));
            }
            query.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Data for promo persisted");
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            em.clear();
            em.close();
        }
```

The error I get is

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : item
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.verifyParametersBound(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.beforeQuery(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.beforeQuery(NativeQueryImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1610)
    at com.danielme.blog.nativesql.dao.UserDao.insertPromoData(UserDao.java:99)
```

However - if I pass non-empty list - this works as expected

```
SQLCustomQuery:72 - Starting processing of sql query [INSERT INTO U_USER_PROMO (ITEM, LOC, WK_START, NUMBER_OF_WEEKS, TYPE, FCSTID, QTY) VALUES (:item, :location, :wkStart, :numberOfWeeks, :type, :fcstId, :quantity)]
AbstractFlushingEventListener:74 - Flushing session
```

Comment: I have updated with the code from my validator class that populates my entity list from a POJO Bean list.  My POJO bean list (promo) seems to have the data set and populated in that list, but then for some reason it looks like my entity bean list is empty while I try to populate it from the POJO list.  Any reason I may not be seeing the data populated into my List<InsertPromoData>?

Comment: I would suggest to use debugger in your IDE to check why the list is empty after getting processed in Validator.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered same problem. I noticed that I was defining the parameter in the query but I was not setting its value in:

```
query.setParameter(parameterToBeSet,parameterValue)
```

For example,

```
String hql = "FROM COLLEGE FETCH ALL PROPERTIES WHERE studentId = :studentId AND departmentId = :departmentId AND studentName = :studentName";

DBConnectionManager.getInstance().invokeCallableOnSessionMasterDB(session -> {
    Query<CollegeEntity> query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("studentId", studentId);
    query.setParameter("departmentId", departmentId);
    values.addAll(query.list());
});
```

As you can see the student name value was not set. So, after adding:

```
query.setParameter("studentName", studentName);
```

It got solved.

Answer (score 0):

GETRequest : localhost:8080/getbyCity/chennai,mumbai,kolkata -

**error** ---> when I send this request I got------->"Hibernate QueryException Named parameter not bound error".

Answer: when we send list of parameter we should mention the "/" at the End. ((( localhost:8080/getbyCity/chennai,mumbai,kolkata/ ))). Set the bound using "/".

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have put same parameter name to the procedure as:

```
@Param("managementAccess") Boolean managementAccess,
@Param("managementAccess") String dealerCode,
@Param("managementAccess") String dealerName,
```

Here the parameter name is different but inside string the name is same.
Solution is:

```
@Param("managementAccess") Boolean managementAccess,
@Param("dealerCode") String dealerCode,
@Param("dealerName") String dealerName,
```